# DNS Settings with external hosted domain

Tags: dns, domain, web-hosting

I have a domain, hosted by Hetzner and a vserver hosted by Hosteurope.
On the vserver I used plesk panel to make a wordpress website.

What are the DNS settings to connect my domain to this website?

At the Hetzner DNS I didn't change anything and the nameservers are "ns.second-ns.com" and so on. But what do I have to set in the DNS settings in my plesk panel for this website? I just set the nameserver adress, but this didn't help.

Domain host:
[image: the settings from domain host]

Answer (score 0):

Web browsers, like most programs, look only for 'A' and/or 'AAAA' records to determine which IP address they should connect to. For example, when visiting `https://www.u████.uk/`, the DNS records of `www.u████.uk` are queried ('A' for IPv4 and/or 'AAAA' for IPv6).

In your DNS control panel, the `@` represents records at the domain base (i.e. `u████.uk` itself), while the subdomain records should be self-explanatory. You decide whether you want to use the bare domain, or the 'www', or both – then you add/change the A records to point to your server's IPv4 address, and the AAAA records to its IPv6 address (preferably).

(I would suggest sorting the table of records by name, not by type, as that's how they're actually grouped in DNS.)

Keep in mind that once the correct IP address is known, the job of DNS is *done* – everything else is configured through your web server (Apache/Nginx/etc), which Plesk should automatically configure for you. Specifically, the web server must know *what* to serve – whether you use the 'www' subdomain or not, the web server's configuration (and possibly the WordPress config, too) needs to match that.

Comment: thank you. so if I understand right, my DNS settings are correct and the problem is the web server. If I deactivate the DNS settings for my site in plesk, everything should work?

Comment: Well, that depends on how it is not working currently. I think I've misread your question, though; will edit the post later.